# Eclipse Plugin - one of the plugin projects in "features" won't compile

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin, compilation, eclipse-pde

My plugin is built by two plugin projects (two plugin projects are in the same workspace).

One of them is an ordinary plugin which has toolbars etc. The other one is a Scala-based XML interpreter.

Everything runs fine and works great while I use `"Run/Debug"` as `"Eclipse Application"`.

But, after I tried to pack it as a `Feature project` then `Build` it with and `Update Site Project`, the auto-generated JARs are wierd: the content of the ordinary plugin JAR is classes, which is correct; however, the other one (in scala), Eclipse packed the JAR with the original file - `filename.scala` in the `JAR`!

In other words, the plugin project didn't get compiled after `Build`(in Update site project by putting `Features` in).

But it worked fine when I used "`Run`" as "`Eclipse Application`".

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or any hint?

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953468/scala-project-wont-compile-in-eclipse-could-not-find-the-main-class) but it didn't fix my problem.