# Error "Could not find or load main class y" when running "scala" command on terminal

Tags: java, scala, powershell, terminal, jvm

I just downloaded and installed Scala 3 from Coursier as the Scala main page suggested.

The problem is, each time I type the `scala` command on the terminal, an error show up saying the following:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class y
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: y
```

I also tried to reinstall Java JDK 17 but it didn't work at all.

The command `scalac` does not work either.

What am I doing wrong? I recently carried out the same process on another computer and it worked just fine.

I look forward to any suggestions or answers you can give me, thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala project won't compile in Eclipse; "Could not find the main class."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953468/scala-project-wont-compile-in-eclipse-could-not-find-the-main-class)

Comment: @MFerguson not really. I'm not trying to compile anything at all. I'm just typing the command "scala" on the terminal, literally just that, I'm not trying to run or compile any .scala file, just typing that command and presssing enter gives me that error :(